# Where is the "Settings" tab in my app? Can't find "Authentication/Authorization"

Tags: authentication, authorization, settings

I've looked over a number of guides to enable Azure AD authentication for my app.  In other words ..."Add Azure Active Directory information to your application".  However, I can not find the "settings" tab for my web app listed anywhere.  I'm looking for the "Authentication/Authorization" screen.  What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance,
Roger

Answer (score 0):

So I found the answer.  The term "app" is these guides is talking about an app under "App Services" not an app in an Azure VM.  Newbie question I guess.